# Android Firebase Realtime Database запросы

Tags: java, android, база-данных, firebase, firebase-database

Есть одна проблема с моей базой данных. Я делаю запрос, чтобы проверить есть ли совпадения у пользователей в никнейме. Структура моей базы следующая:

```
users: {
    тут я просто вставляю uid пользователя: {
        niclName: "Vasya"
    }
}
```

Дак вот как мне осуществить поиск по всем юзерам (точнее по их uid) и далее уже по их никнейму.

Для поиска никнейма я использую следующий запрос:

```
Query searchMatch = myRef.child("users").child("userId").child("nickName").equalTo(nickName);
```

И это, логично, не работает. Может мне нужно использовать `orderBy...();`?

Comment: .child("userId") тут что строка или реальный uid?

Comment: @ValeraKvip это просто строка.

Comment: а должен быть id пользователя

Comment: @ValeraKvip тогда я буду проверять есть ли у текущего пользователя никнейм. Конечно у него его нет. Возможно вы мне меня не так поняли. Мне нужно перебрать uid всех пользователей и их nickName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй подобный запрос, у меня работает.
`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("users").orderByChild("nickName").equalTo(nickName).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(Здесь ValueEventListener{})`

Далее в методе onDataChange проверяешь равно ли полученное значение нулю или нет. Если ты получил значение, то подобный ник уже есть, если равно null, то нет